# Cross-domain AJAX POST script works, but there is no callback on success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cors, jquery-forms-plugin

On a http site I have a form with submit leading to other domain:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="https://(...)/script.php" method="post"> (...)
```

In order to enable cross-domain AJAX I've added to script.php:

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

and now the script can be accessed, but I guess it doesn't give response back to the server, because the callback method on success:

```
$("form").ajaxSubmit({
                    target:        '.afterSend',
                    beforeSubmit:  showRequest,
                    success:       showResponse

                });
```

which is

```
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  { 

    $(".afterSend").removeClass("preloader");               
    $(".afterSend").empty().append(responseText);

}
```

never fires up, despite successful AJAX call:
[image]

It worked when both files were on same domain.

**EDIT:** 
When I add option `complete: showResponse` there is no `responseText`. 
When I add `error: showResponse` I get warning:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (...) on line 14

but `responseText` shows. 
So it seems that because of that warning jQuery perceived call as an unsuccessful.

Comment: Have you observed the request / response in the browser's console? You may also want to add an error handler to your AJAX request.

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes, I've edited the question. response is 200 (OK)

Comment: What is line 14 of your PHP file?

Comment: `<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>`